# How to display all category images for single post in a page?

Tags: categories

Here is my code

```
<div class="our_team_box_big">
<h2>Microsoft</h2>
<?php foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : ?>
<div class="one_fourth">
<div class="two_third"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></div>
<strong><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></strong>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

`z_taxonomy_image_url()`, is a category image plugin... Actually whats the my need is I am trying to access the all category images for a single post (i.e., I am craeting 5 categories and one post, how can I call all category images into that post?). I am using wordpress category image plugin

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what it is exactly you're trying to accomplish? What is `z_taxonomy_image_url()` function?

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_category()` isn't the correct function - you should be using `get_categories()` per the [dev documentation](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/).